# Is LIAPP a good substitute for Dexguard

Tags: android-security

Dexguard is currently too expensive for me as I seek to protect my Android app. I'm considering LIAPP (https://liapp.lockincomp.com/), but would like to know what others think of its effectiveness in protecting my app's assets and in protecting against hacking and reverse engineering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested LIAPP on my app, and it worked, so I've now purchased it.

Comment: Which plan did you purchase?

Comment: I purchased a single ticket